# Comparison of sets in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pattern-matching, database-performance

I have a challenge with the following database structure:

- HEADER table called 'DOC' containing document details among which the document ID
- DETAIL tabel called 'DOC_SET' containing data related to the document.

The header table is approximately 16000 records. The detail table contains on average 75 records per header table (1.2 million records in total).

I have one source document and its related set (source set). This source set I like to compare to the other documents' sets (which I refer to as destination documents and sets). Through my application I have a list of ID's of the source set available and as such also the length (in the example below shown as a list of 46 elements) which I can use in the query directly.

What I need per destination document is the length of the intersection (number of shared elements) of the source and destination sets and the length of the difference (length of what is in the source set and what is not in the destination set) for display. I also need a filter to retrieve only records for which a 75% intersection between source and destination, compared to the source set is reached.

Currently I have a query which does this by using sub selects containing expressions, but it is utterly slow and the results need to be available at page refresh in a web application. The point is I only need to display about 20 results at a time, but when sorting on calculated fields I need to calculate every destination record before being able to sort and paginate.

The query is something like this:

```
            select
                DOC.id,
                calc_subquery._calcSetIntersection,
                calc_subquery._calcSetDifference
            from
                DOC
            inner join
                (
                    select
                        DOC.id as document_id,
                        (
                            select
                                count(*)
                            from
                                DOC_SET
                            where
                                DOC_SET.doc_id = DOC.id and
                                DOC_SET.element_id in (60,114,130,187,267,394,421,424,426,603,604,814,909,1035,1142,1223,1314,1556,2349,2512,4953,5134,6318,6339,6344,6455,6528,6601,6688,6704,6705,6731,6894,6895,7033,7088,7103,7119,7129,7132,7133,7137,7154,7159,7188,7201)
                        ) as _calcSetIntersection
                        ,46-(
                            select
                                count(*)
                            from
                                DOC_SET
                            where
                                DOC_SET.doc_id = DOC.id and
                                DOC_SET.element_id in (60,114,130,187,267,394,421,424,426,603,604,814,909,1035,1142,1223,1314,1556,2349,2512,4953,5134,6318,6339,6344,6455,6528,6601,6688,6704,6705,6731,6894,6895,7033,7088,7103,7119,7129,7132,7133,7137,7154,7159,7188,7201)
                        ) as _calcSetDifference
                    from
                        DOC
                    where
                        DOC.id = 2599   
                ) as calc_subquery
            on
                DOC.id = calc_subquery.document_id
            where
                DOC.id = 2599 and
                _calcSetIntersection / 46 > 0.75;
```

I'm wondering if:

- this is possible while being performed in < 100msec or so on MySQL
  on an average spec server running MySQL fully in memory (24Gb).
- I should use a better suiting solution for this, perhaps like a NoSQL solution.
- If I should use some sort of temporary table or cache containing
  calculated values. This is an issue for me as the source set of id's
  might change in between queries and the whole thing needs to be
  calculated again.

Anyway, some thoughts or solutions are really appreciated.

Kind regards,
Eric